# unable to call shp2pgsql using python

Tags: python, postgis

I am unable to call shp2pgsql using python as I  have to pass various options like `(-s -a -i)`
and I am not getting the required output ..

Method I am using is

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", "shp2pgsql","-a","-s 4326","roads.shp" "roads", ">","roads.sql"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

>>>p1.communicate()[0]
```

as my intension is to add the features of the shapefile into the already existing table in the database

I am done with the environment settings..
roads.shp is the name of the shapefile 
roads is the table name 
and roads.sql is the sql file name..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a bit convoluted. Why not use [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) instead? Just write out / manipulate the command as a string and feed it to os.system.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest  you can use the following codes:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", "shp2pgsql","-a","-s 4326","roads.shp", "roads"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p1.communicate()
with open('roads.sql', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(stdout)
```

Another alternative method (if you want to import this into postgresql database):

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", "shp2pgsql","-a","-s 4326","roads.shp", "roads"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['psql',  '-d db'], stdin=p1.stdout, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
stdout, stderr= p2.communicate()
```

References:

1. http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate
2. http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline